# How to get old certificate in expo and resign the new apk?

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I have created an apk with `exp build:android` and published it in Google Store for internal testing with the certificate that was, as I believe, generated by expo. After that I have changed `"name"` and `"splash"` fields in `app.json` and run `exp build:android` again. This time expo has generated another certificate and signed the apk with it.

So the problem is when I'm trying to add an apk with new version of code to the Google, it says that I should have the same certificate to load the file. How can I do that? Is there a way of getting an old certificate from expo and signing the new .apk with it or the only way is to create a new app in Google Console?

**Update:**

I was able to give the same certificate to the new build. For this you just need to add `expo.slug` field to your app.json file. There you can write your app name (see it in your apps on the expo site, in address bar in browser) and it will use the same key as before then. However I still don't know how to get the certificate from there.